A few questions on bracket polynomial
I have a few questions about bracket polynomials.



We have the above equation, but when calculating the value of the figure D for a given link L, does the order in which this equation is applied matter?
In other words, does it depend on the order of the intersections I choose?

If it does not depend on the choice, why is that?

Thank you for helping.

It wouldn't be well-defined if the order mattered! This is, to be clear, surprising and not obvious.

@QiaochuYuan Surprisingly, this isn't the surprising part. The order doesn't matter for the same reason that when you apply the distributive law in $(A_1+B_1)(A_2+B_2)\cdots(A_n+B_n)$ the order doesn't matter. The surprising part is that Reidemeister moves II and III don't affect the result (and Reidemeister move I only affects it by multiplication by some power of $-A^3$).
